# MySQL Performance Monitoring

Tags: mysql, monitoring

I already have system availability monitoring for all my MySQL instances in Nagios.  I'm looking to get some trending monitoring going for activity. It'd be nice to see how all the `information_schema` stats trend over time, to help identify sources of problems etc.

I've seen Cacti exists and seems pretty popular.

What have your experiences with Cacti been (pros/cons)?

Are there any other common solutions I should investigate?

Answer (score 3):

If  you're looking for graphs, Cacti (or Munin) will work. I've personally only used Munin.

However, I wouldn't put much stock in graphs to troubleshoot problems that arise. If it's showing in the graphs, it's been going on too long.

I would get familiar with the [maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) or [percona](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/) tools (I think percona is a fork of maatkit) for trouble shooting problems.

Answer (score 3):

There are [open source tools from Percona](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/). Try `pt-mysql-summary` and `pt-variable-advisor`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a daemon that logs the results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW MUTEX STATUS every x seconds to [graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) or a CSV.  You may find it useful: https://github.com/9minutesnooze/mysampler.  It can provide you insight into all the MySQL status information at whatever granularity you choose.  There isn't any documentation yet, but I have found the output highly useful, either by pulling the CSV into gnuplot or (better) viewing the results in graphite to correlate with other metrics.  I plan on extending it soon to parse SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS as well.  I'm sure there is other data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA that would be valuable to add in, but I haven't gotten there yet.

For slightly less granular and more processed results, the [Percona Cacti Templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/wiki/MySQLTemplates) are very good, but only show problems that have existed for a "long" time.  They do show some interesting trending information and, as with most charts and graphs, the differences over time are what tend to be most enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Jet Profiler is great for monitoring MySQL.  Works like SQL Server profiler, but it includes graphs and charts.

http://www.jetprofiler.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to see live, customizable trending graphs over the past 2-5 minutes, you should use MySQL Administrator. Believe it or not, although it went EOL December 18, 2009, the last version of MySQL Administrator is still available for download for free. Hey, I still it them today.

[**Click here and get it while Oracle isn't looking ... QUICK !!!**](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)